# CXF + Spring: No root resource matching request path has been found

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, cxf

Trying to get a REST service with CXF and Spring up and running and I hit this wall. Everything else looks fine since I can access my /services/ page and see MyService listed under the REST services. I can view the WADL of the service just fine, with my method appearing there. When I try to access it though, exception occurs.

```
WARNING: No root resource matching request path /testApp/services/MyService/goTest has been found, Relative Path: /goTest. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
Jul 19, 2016 4:30:50 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
```

My service interface

```
@Path("/MyService")
@Service
public interface MyService {

    @GET
    @Path("/goTest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testService();
}
```

Service implementation:

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

public Response testService() {
        // Code

        return Response.status(200).entity(gson.toJson(json)).build();
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
 @Configuration
 public class WebServiceSpringConfig {

    @Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
        public SpringBus springBus() {
            return new SpringBus();
        }


        @Bean
        public Server MyService() {

            JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
            endpoint.setBus(springBus());
            endpoint.setAddress("/MyService");
            endpoint.setServiceBean(new MyServiceImpl());
            return endpoint.create();
        }
    }
```

Spring config and CXF servlet are declared in the web.xml

I'm using Spring 4.2.0 with CXF 3.1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url goTest could be access as shown below.

```
http://<ip-add>:<port>/<web-root>/services/MyService/MyService/goTest
```

in short add MyService again as you have set MyService as `setAddress` and also as `@Path`

```
/testApp/services/MyService/MyService/goTest
```

Comment: This solution helped me as well, the reason I was getting a similar error was because I hadn't appended the class level path declaration with the method level one. I was trying (<url>/methodLevelPath should have been <url>/classLevelPath/classLevelPath) thanks.